# How to seed a .js file using mongoid in Rails

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, seeding

I am trying out Mongoid in rails4.

I need to seed a .js file in the Mongoid database. How is that done? I have a .js file in my db/ folder but can't figure out how to seed it...

Comment: what do you mean you want to seed a js file?

Comment: I have some data in a seed.js file that I need to use as my initial seed data for Mongoid databse.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue a while back, but was using MongoMapper not Mongoid.

I was able to seed the mongo database from a .js file using this command:

`mongo [database_name] [seed_file_path]`

ex: `mongo my_db db/seed.js`

I found the database name in the mongo.yml file which was created by MongoMapper.  I think it would be mongoid.yml with Mongoid.

Hope this helps.